# Other footnote-kinds

Tags: footnotes

I'd like to create these kinds of footnotes:

1. The numbers between (), [], {};
2. The numbers in circles and boxes;
3. Footnotes in `$...$, $$...$$, \begin{equation}...\end{equation}`-and-`\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}`--environments.

How could I do?

Thank you

Comment: You can check maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisx

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help me much

Comment: Not related, but you should use `\[…\]` instead of `$$…$$`

Comment: Why? What changes?

Comment: Do you want different types of footnote in the same document, or to make a style change for the whole of the document? Also, I don't think there is anything that prevents you from putting a footnote in an equation (though it's usually not a good idea, because the symbol or number can easily be confused with mathematical notation). Therefore I'm not sure what you want under (3).

Comment: For your question following the comment @LuisTurcio from, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2417).

Comment: Yes, I mean footnote in equations, preferibly of kind: [#1] or {#1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for

1. \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}; \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}; \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{{\arabic{footnote}}};
2. Not yet for circle;
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\boxed{\arabic{footnote}}}
3. Not yet

When someone will find a solution, please edit this message! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different types of footnote using the [manyfoot package](https://ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot). If you want a special type of footnote to use in equations, then you can use two types and `\ifmmode` to test whether you are currently in math mode. Personally, I would advise against using footnotes in equations, since the symbol or number can easily be mistaken for a piece of mathematical notation. Nevertheless...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}

\newcounter{footnoteA}
\newcommand\footnoteA{%
\stepcounter{footnoteA}%
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteA \FootnotetextA{}}

\newcounter{footnoteB}
\newcommand\footnoteB{%
\stepcounter{footnoteB}%
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteB \FootnotetextB\thefootnoteB}

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{[\#\roman{footnoteB}]}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\ifmmode\footnoteB{#1}\else\footnoteA{#1}\fi}

\newfootnote{A}
\newfootnote{B}
\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnoteA{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\lipsum[2]\footnoteB{but lands on a sharp spike}
\lipsum[3]\myfootnote{and dies}
\[
e = mc^2\myfootnote{His advice from beyond is to avoid footnotes in equations.}
\]
\end{document}
```

The code for creating `\footnoteA` and `\footnoteB` is taken from the manyfoot package documentation.

Comment: How can I improve this: `\newcommand{\Footnote}[1]{({#1})}`? Thx.

Comment: Thx you for your answer, but it does not answer at my question.

Comment: @Puck --- Unfortunately, I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you could clarify your question.

Comment: @Puck Your question asked how to create many footnote styles making effectively 6 questions in one when the site much prefers single questions. Also you did not show what you had tried. Ian Thompson's answer showed how to create different footnote styles. Did you expect an answer for each of your 6 styles? You did not do any work yourself in your question so be grateful for what work others do for you. --- GOM

Comment: Ok, exscuse me. The @Ian Thompson's Answer is useful for me because it teaches how create other footnote kinds. I wanted ask you how create footnotes in equations, tabulars and how I can create footnotes with number in a circle (for box I already done). Thanks at all!

Comment: And then, GOM means what? Thx

Comment: @Puck GOM = Grumpy Old Man